Questions on Effectively Denumerable Sets and Universal Programs in Computability Theory
I'm currently reading the book Computability: An Introduction to Recursive Function Theory by Nigel Cutland.
I find this book very good, but I have two unresolved questions about it:

Definition of "effectively denumerable"

The author defines this as follows:
"Let X be a set of finite objects; then X is effectively denumerable if there is a bijection $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that both $f$ and its inverse function are effectively computable functions. (We mean here the informal notion of effectively computable. this is compelled on us since, in general, there is no available formal notion of computability of functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{N}$.)"
The author uses the notion of URM-computability, and since a unary function that is URM-computable must map $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, this is why the author says, "there is no available formal notion of computability for functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{N}$."
But when we define something, don't we have to base the definition on an already established formal notion? In other words, is it appropriate to use an informal notion of effectively computable here?

Universal function

The universal function takes two inputs: one is the index of a program, and the other is a tuple of natural numbers that will serve as the input to the program.
The author proves that this universal function is computable by appealing to Church's thesis:
"Decode the number (e) and write out the program (P_e). Now mimic the computation (P_e(x)) step by step, ... If and when this computation stops, then the required value is the number currently in (R1)."
My concern is: where do we "write out" the program (P_e)? Is it on the URM machine's registers? After decoding the single number to identify the program, how and where can we store or represent the instructions that make up the program?


You have two questions in one MSE post here. You will likely get a better response if you raise two separate posts. You should also say what "URM" means ("universal register machine"?).

You can use the dollar sign for math instead of parenthesis

I thought the same when reading the first fragment: the author is being informal in the definition of an effectively denumerable set. I'm going to offer an alternative formulation.
Let an effectively denumerated set be a set
$X$ together with an invertible function $\varphi : X \to \mathbb N$. Then we can define a notion of computability for functions between effectively denumerated sets: we say that $f : (X, \varphi) \to (Y, \psi)$ is computable if $\psi \circ f \circ \varphi^{-1}$ is URM-computable.
The above notion results in an uninteresting category where every two objects are isomorphic, so it's no wonder it's never defined. However, we are interested in a different problem: given two effective denumerations $\varphi, \psi$ on the same set $X,$ are they equivalent? (In the sense that they define the same computable functions)
That is, is $\varphi\circ\psi^{-1}$ URM-computable? (If it is, then its inverse $\psi\circ\varphi^{-1}$ is computable too.)
Not in general, of course. However, it's good to know that, in (some versions of) constructive mathematics, every function $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ that you can define is computable. Thus any informal denumeration of a given set is going to be equivalent, as long as you avoid the use of the Law of Excluded Middle (including the Axiom of Choice in its typical form) in its definition.
For example, take the next definition of an uncomputable invertible function $\varphi : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N.$

Set $x = 0.$ Set two counters $m=0,\ n=1$ and then:

If $P_x(x)$ halts then set $\varphi(x) = m$ and increase $m$ by 2.
If $P_x(x)$ does not halt then set $\varphi(x) = n$ and increase $n$ by 2.

In any case, increase $x$ by one and repeat.

This would give a different notion of computability in $\mathbb N$. However, this definition depends on the Law of Excluded Middle, in the form "either $P_x(x)$ halts or it does not".
So, in short, even though two effective denumerations on a set might give different definitions of computability, the typical "set of finite objects" can always be defined in a constructive theory, and then any effective denumeration on the same set is going to be equivalent.
As for the second question, the appendix shows a more detailed proof. The intermediate variables are saved in registers. However, once you get accustomed to computability, you will see that an informal description of an algorithm does correspond to a program, but it's hard before you study the proof of the universal program.
